# Frame location change bug

Tags: javascript, frames

I have successfully changed the location of frames on my page using commands like:

```
parent.bottomframe.location = 'interstitial.html';.
```

This one particular call, however, isn't working. I am calling a js function from the 'onclick' of a button in html. This function does most of its work successfully, and also successfully changes the text of my top frame using

```
parent.topframe.document.getElementById("tutorial").innerHTML = text;
```

But the bottom frame doesn't change. Could it be that I'm losing permission to change this property? If I put an alert() after the location-change line, I get back the old location, not the new one.

Any ideas?

(Here's the code for this function:)

```
function GetInterstitial(found_target)
{
parent.topframe.current_trial++;

if (found_target)
{
    parent.topframe.correct++;
}
if (parent.topframe.current_trial==parent.topframe.total_trials)
{
    UpdateData(parent.topframe.output);
    setTimeout(function()
        {SendAllData();}, 0
        );
    parent.topframe.document.getElementById("tutorial").innerHTML = thank_you_text[0]+parent.topframe.correct.toString()+'/'+parent.topframe.total_trials.toString()+thank_you_text[1];
    parent.bottomframe.location.href = 'http://urlname..../js/thankyou.html?c='+parent.topframe.userID;
}
else
{
    if (found_target)
        text = "<p>Great job; you found the hidden number! Now click 'next' to play the next round.</p>";
    else
        text = "<p>Hmm... it seems you didn't find the hidden number. Click 'next' to play the next round.</p>";
}

setTimeout(function()
    {
        UpdateData(parent.topframe.output);
    },600);

parent.topframe.document.getElementById("tutorial").innerHTML = text; //interstitial_text;
parent.bottomframe.location = 'interstitial.html';
parent.topframe.trial++;
parent.topframe.document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: show us your code otherwise we cant help you

Comment: It sounds like you're sending the bottom frame somewhere and then trying to modify the document, is that the case? If so, it probably hasn't loaded yet. Instead of modifying it right away, try setting an onload handler.

Comment: It turns out that the problem was in the fact that the above function was being called by an onclick() event in the .html page, and this event was within <frame></frame> tags. Moving these tags to elsewhere in the page fixed the problem. If anybody can enlighten me as to why this helped, I'd appreciate it!